# Can these simple graphs exists?

Tags: graph-theory

Can these two graphs exist?

$5$ vertices and the vertices need degrees of $1, 1, 2, 2, 3$

and

$5$ vertices and the vertices need degrees of $1, 2, 2, 2, 3$

These do have to simple graphs and I would really appreciate any help or explanation you guys have. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

The sum of the degree must be even because each edge contributes to degree $2$.

For the possible one, draw a square and make some adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

The key ingredient here is the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma): the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges.  Since $1+1+2+2+3=9$, the sequence $(1,1,2,2,3)$ cannot be graphical (i.e., there's no graph with that degree sequence).

There are two graphs up to isomorphism with the degree sequence (1,2,2,2,3):

[image: The two graphs with degree sequence (1,2,2,2,3)]

These could be found by hand, but I instead used `geng` (which comes with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/)) to generate all $5$-vertex graphs with $\frac{1}{2}(1+2+2+2+3)$ edges and filtered out the ones with the wrong degree sequence with a script.